# Why am I unable to import IntFlag class from enum.py module?

Tags: python, enums

I am trying to run this piece of code:

```
from enum import IntFlag
```

But I am getting this error: "ImportError: cannot import name 'IntFlag'"

However, if I run

```
from enum import EnumMeta
```

I get no error. 
The version of python I am using is Python35 and the enum.py file that I am using can be found here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/enum.py

Also, my enum.py file is located here: C:\Python35\lib\enum.py

And I have uninstalled enum34

Comment: 3.5 != 3.6, are you sure about those numbers?

Comment: @o11c I copy pasted the code from that github link to my enum.py file. The original enum.py file I had did not have a IntFlag class.

Comment: "New in version 3.6: Flag, **IntFlag**, auto" Your version of Python doesn't have `IntFlag`.

Comment: @chepner so using the 3.6 version of enum.py will not work?

Comment: See the note about `IntFlag`in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#module-contents) — it's new in version **3.6**.

Comment: No, that's the exact opposite of what I'm saying. You are getting an `ImportError` because you *aren't* using 3.6, the earliest version that defines `IntFlag`.

Comment: @chepner I copy pasted the code from that github link(3.6 version) to my enum.py file though.

Comment: Apparently just pulling in the 3.6 version of `enum.py` isn't enough to make it work in 3.5 — so upgrading would probably be the easiest thing to do.

Comment: Python 3 uses absolute imports by default; you are certainly still importing `enum` from the standard library, regardless of whatever local `enum.py` you have.

Comment: Ah okay. So upgrading from 3.5 is the only answer?

Comment: It's unclear from everything you've said whether you've tried it or not, but replacing the `C:\Python35\lib\enum.py` with the one from version 3.6 _might_ work, but messing around with the standard library like that is asking for trouble.

Comment: @chepner one last question about the absolute import of python. When I ran print(enum.__file__), I got the file path that I posted in my original post. Is that not the module that it's using when I type "from enum import ..."?

Comment: @martineau I did this: "replacing the C:\Python35\lib\enum.py with the one from version 3.6".

Comment: Well, in that case just using the 3.6 version of that one file doesn't work in Python 3.5. There are a number of possible reasons that could be, which is why I said it would probably be easier to just upgrade. In fact, if you're going to do that, might as well go all the way up to v3.8.1 which is currently the latest AFAIK.

Comment: @chepner: a user script that imports `enum` will get a local copy before the stdlib version -- shadowing stdlib modules is still a thing.

Comment: @EthanFurman Depends on where the local copy is. The OP is indicating that it is *not* being imported, though.

Comment: @chepner: Sounds to me like the OP replaced the one in `C:\Python35\lib`.

Comment: @AJHello:  open `C:\Python35\lib\enum.py` and verify it's the new version (in other words, see if it has an `IntFlag` in it).

Comment: @EthanFurman yes C:\Python35\lib\enum.py is the 3.6 version(the github link in my original post) and has the class IntFlag in it.

Comment: @AJHello: The only idea I have left is that the stdlib is actually in a zip file or dll and is ignoring your newer `enum.py` -- and I could easily be wrong.

Comment: @EthanFurman how would I check if what you are saying is happening?

Comment: @AJHello:  I don't know -- I haven't used Windows in years. :-(